# Append data at end of existing data with SORT

Tags: sorting, mainframe, dfsort

I want the below code to work for variable length data also in input. So, that I can append double quote at its end. I don't want to use COBOL. Is it possible?

1. ZZZZ.VVVV.FILE.CORR1 contains following records:-

   ```
   ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB0001.csv  
   ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB0002.csv  
   ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB0003.csv
   ```
2. Output records in file ZZZZ.VVVV.FILE.CORR2 by following code is:

   ```
   r_file1="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB0001.csv"  
   r_file2="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB0002.csv"  
   r_file3="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB0003.csv"
   ```

JCL code is:

```
//STEPSRT5 EXEC PGM=SORT                                              
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*                                               
//SORTIN   DD  DSN=ZZZZ.VVVV.FILE.CORR1,       <ID>
//             DISP=SHR                                               
//SORTOUT  DD  DSN=ZZZZ.VVVV.FILE.CORR2,      <OD>
//             DCB=(RECFM=FB,LRECL=80,BLKSIZE=0),                     
//             SPACE=(27920,(29,6),RLSE),                             
//             DISP=(NEW,CATLG,DELETE)                                
//SYSIN    DD  *                                                      
 SORT FIELDS=COPY                                                     
 OUTREC FIELDS=(1:C'r_file',7:SEQNUM,1,ZD,8:C'="',10:1,26,36:C'"',44X)
/*
```

Comment: Which sort are you using IBM or Sync Sort. Also Read the manual before asking. Here is IBM manual reference for variable fields http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.iceg200/ice1cg4043.htm, and for VB try http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.iceg200/ice1cg4043.htm

Comment: You have to fully define your question. Update your question with what you want with everything you want.

Comment: @NealB has a nice SQZ example for you for your new, as yet undocumented, requirement. It does bring one thing up. If you ever look at your r_files in sequence, r_file2 will come next to r_file20. Why, if you can have r_file10, don't you have r_file01? The use of SQZ I was thinking of before the spec change was to get the closing double-quote with TRAIL='"'. Until or unless you define your full requirement, you've probably got all that you're going to get.

Answer (score 2):

```
 SORT FIELDS=COPY                                                     
 INREC BUILD=(C'r_file',SEQNUM,1,ZD,C'="',5,44,80:X)
 OUTREC FINDREP=(STARTPOS=14,IN=C' ',OUT=C'"',DO=1)
```

This is not JCL by the way, They are SORT Control Cards. You find all the details in the manual for your site's SORT product.

INREC/OUTREC/OUTFIL can contain one only of BUILD, OVERLAY, IFTHEN or one or more IFTHENs. Two ways to do it since you want two functions used unconditionally is like the above, or with two IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE with the function-use part of the IFTHEN.

Your records are not variable. They are fixed-length (or your existing code would not work) likely 80 bytes (if not 80, change the 80:X appropriately).

Bear in mind that you will get duplicate sequence-numbers with more than 10 input records (and the tenth is going to give you r_file0).

You could also look at SQZ (squeeze) since you have no embedded blanks in your data.

Comment: SORT FIELDS=COPY INREC BUILD=(C'r_file',7:SEQNUM,1,ZD,8:C'="',10:1,44,80:X) OUTREC FINDREP=(STARTPOS=14,IN=C' ',OUT=C'"',DO=1). This is working fine. But for r_file10, there will be problem. How can I use SQZ here?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
//STEP01   EXEC PGM=SORT
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*
//SORTOUT  DD  SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD  *
 SORT FIELDS=COPY
 INREC BUILD=(C'r_file',SEQNUM,3,CSF,C'="',1,68,C'"')
 OUTREC BUILD=(1,80,SQZ=(SHIFT=LEFT))
/*
//SORTIN   DD  *
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB0001.csv
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB0002.csv
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB0003.csv
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_0702.csv
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_AAAYZ0702.csv
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB.csv
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_XXXXXXXAMY0702.csv
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_YZ0702.csv
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_C0702.csv
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_0702.csv
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_702.csv
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_02.csv
ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_2.csv
/*
//SORTMSG DD SYSOUT=*
//
```

SORTOUT will contain:

```
r_file1="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB0001.csv"
r_file2="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB0002.csv"
r_file3="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB0003.csv"
r_file4="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_0702.csv"
r_file5="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_AAAYZ0702.csv"
r_file6="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_BBB.csv"
r_file7="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_XXXXXXXAMY0702.csv"
r_file8="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_YZ0702.csv"
r_file9="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_C0702.csv"
r_file10="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_0702.csv"
r_file11="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_702.csv"
r_file12="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_02.csv"
r_file13="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_2.csv"
```

`INREC` builds a record something like:

```
    r_file 10="ABCDEFG_AAAAAA_0702.csv                                       "
```

The trick is to use `CFS` for the sequence number so that they are created with leading spaces, that way we do not get messed up trying to trim leading zeros as would required with `ZD` (`SQZ` with `PREBLANK=C'0'` to get rid of leading zeros just doesn't work - it gets rid of all zeros, including imbeded and trailing)

Next `OUTREC` squeezes the spaces out of the record leaving the file name as you require it to be presented.

**Note:** This solution assumes that your file names do not contain imbedded spaces. If they do, there is more tinkering to be done.

Comment: You still have one superfluous column number from the original (7:). Your output is 92 bytes, not 80. An EDIT can do the leading space. Leading zeros are not onerous for a two or three digit number. Why OUTREC FIELDS not OUTREC BUILD? The tinkering for spaces in the filename is interesting :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger Made some of your suggested changes (column number and record length)... What would be the advantage of `OUTREC BUILD` over `OUTREC FIELDS` be?

Comment: Thanks. The BUILD vs FIELDS is a clarity thing. FIELDS is "old" and available for backwards-compatibility. BUILD is new. They are identical. In fact in DFSORT, BUILD is "aliased" to FIELDS in INREC, OUTREC and OUTFIL (says Frank Yaeger, who should know). FIELDS is overloaded. Using BUILD on INREC, OUTREC and OUTFIL, and not using OUTFIL OUTREC= is simply for clarity. FIELDS is otherwise used on SORT, MERGE, SUM, REFORMAT, JOINKEYS... where FIELDS can mean different things in different places. BUILD is used in INREC,  OUTREC and OUTFIL, and means the same each time.

Comment: @BillWoodger Changed `FIELDS` to `BUILD`, might as well bring things up to date!

Comment: Just noticed I had the column number in mine as well :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger and where do you think I copied that redundant column number from in the first place... :-P

Comment: Dear NealB, I have only renamed datasets and its values due to security reasons. Please approve it.